# How to prioritize to read specific file name first in zip file upload in PHP

Tags: php

I am uploading a zip file, having multilpe text files. I want to read or process spacific files first. How its possible. Code structure is

```
    $zip = zip_open($file_zip_name);
    while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    {       
         $TableName = strstr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), '.', true);
    }
```

It read files alphabetically while i want to read files by my sequence.

Comment: The problem lies with the zip archive: it is not a directory, but a very different structure: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format) Files inside are already ordered by the archive *creator*, not by the unpacker. What you could do is read the archive into some temporary structure and sort *that* as you wish.

Comment: `$names_array = array();
   while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
   {
    $names_array[] = strstr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), '.', true);
   }
   echo"<pre>"; print_r($names_array); 
   
   while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    { 
     echo"inter"; exit;
                              }`

inter didnt print, it means not reached to here. whats the reason ??

Comment: You have already read all the `$zip` entries; trying to read them *again* will give you `false`, as expected. Maybe you are trying to do `foreach ($names_array as $zip_entry)`  instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can read all files to memory or make copy on disk, names in array, than sort that array with `usort()` and loop that array to process files. But I don't think it's good idea, because it's waste of resources just to sort files. Is there really such big difference?

Comment: $names_array = array();
   while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
   {
    $names_array[] = strstr(zip_entry_name($zip_entry), '.', true);
   }
   echo"<pre>"; print_r($names_array); 
   
   while($zip_entry = zip_read($zip))
    { 
     echo"inter"; exit;
                              }

inter didnt print, it means not reached to here. whats the reason ??